ST_GEOGFROMTEXT Multipolygons converted to Polygons in BigQuery
I've stumbled upon an intriguing issue while working with MultiPolygons in BigQuery. When utilizing the ST_GEOGFROMTEXT function to parse a MultiPolygon containing multiple polygons, the output unexpectedly returns only one of the constituent polygons, rather than a MultiPolygon as anticipated.
Here's an example of the query causing the puzzling behavior:
SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0)), ((2 2, 8 2, 8 8, 2 8, 2 2)))', make_valid => true);

Returns:
POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))

and the make valid parameter seems to not make a difference here...another example:
SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('MULTIPOLYGON(((84.1 55.8, 84.2 55.8, 84.2 55.9, 84.1 55.9, 84.1 55.8)),((84.15 55.85, 84.18 55.85, 84.18 55.88, 84.15 55.88, 84.15 55.85)))');

Returns:
POLYGON((84.1 55.8, 84.2 55.8, 84.2 55.9, 84.1 55.9, 84.1 55.8))

Both the above examples are polygons inside polygons, and hence creating the issue, when the polygons are disjointed we get the correct result:
SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)), ((2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 2 3, 2 2)), ((4 4, 5 4, 5 5, 4 5, 4 4)))');

Returns:
MULTIPOLYGON(((4 4, 5 4, 5 5, 4 5, 4 4)), ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)), ((2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 2 3, 2 2)))

This is quite confusing, I have also tried ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON with these and the same results...
Another interesting thing that might help is:
    WITH example AS(
  SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(0 1)') AS geography
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('MULTILINESTRING((2 2, 3 4), (5 6, 7 7))')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOINT(-1 2, 0 12), LINESTRING(-2 4, 0 6))')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)), ((2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 2 3, 2 2)), ((4 4, 5 4, 5 5, 4 5, 4 4)))')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('MULTIPOLYGON(((84.1 55.8, 84.2 55.8, 84.2 55.9, 84.1 55.9, 84.1 55.8)),((84.15 55.85, 84.18 55.85, 84.18 55.88, 84.15 55.88, 84.15 55.85)))'))

SELECT
  geography AS WKT,
  ST_GEOMETRYTYPE(geography) AS geometry_type_name
FROM example;


How can I render a multipolygon (having polygon inside a polygon) correctly?

Holes are single-nested, and should be reverse-wrapped. 'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0), (2 2, 2 8, 8 8, 8 2, 2 2)))'

From the OGC Simple Features standard (multipolygon is a subtype of multisurface):

6.1.13 MultiSurface
6.1.13.1 Description
A MultiSurface is a 2-dimensional GeometryCollection whose elements
are Surfaces, all using coordinates from  the same coordinate
reference system. The geometric interiors of any two Surfaces in a
MultiSurface may not  intersect in the full coordinate system. The
boundaries of any two coplanar elements in a MultiSurface may
intersect, at most, at a finite number of Points. If they were to meet
along a curve, they could be merged into a  single surface.

The input multipolygon with overlapping polygon members is invalid. How to make is valid is undefined. PostGIS makes the correction this way:
SELECT ST_AsText(
    ST_MakeValid
    ('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0)), ((2 2, 8 2, 8 8, 2 8, 2 2)))')); 

"MULTIPOLYGON(((0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0,0 10),(8 2,8 8,2 8,2 2,8 2)))"


By the Simple Features standard overlapping polygons can be presented as geometry collection but I do not know if BigQuery can handle them.
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( POLYGON (( 0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0 )), POLYGON (( 2 2, 8 2, 8 8, 2 8, 2 2 )))

